# import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText Failed

Tags: android, importerror

I am building a Login-Register app on Android Studio. When i try to import the package android.support.design.widget it does not recognize it. I searched for a solution on other posts and they say to add some "compile" lines on build.gradle. I did it but nothing works.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is your logcat show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: What makes you think **appcompat-v7** contains `TextInputEditText`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```